# Monster Slayer Ranger vs Enervation

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger

If a Monster Slayer Ranger has Enervation cast on her, chooses to use her Slayer's counter ability, deals damage, breaks the spellcaster's concentration, does she still take the 2d8 damage from passing the save even though the spellcaster is no longer concentrating on the spell?

The Monster Slayer Ranger subclass gets the [Slayer's Counter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Slayer%E2%80%99sCounter-733) ability.

> At 15th level, you gain the ability to counter attack when your prey tries to sabotage you. If the target of your Slayer's Prey forces you to make a saving throw, you can use your reaction to make one weapon attack against the quarry. You make this attack immediately before making the saving throw. If your attack hits, your save automatically succeeds, in addition to the attack's normal effects.

The Text of the spell [Enervation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Enervation) is as follows.

> Duration: Concentration, up to 1 minute
>
> A tendril of inky darkness reaches out from you, touching a creature you can see within range to drain life from it. The target must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a successful save, the target takes 2d8 necrotic damage, and the spell ends. On a failed save, the target takes 4d8 necrotic damage, and until the spell ends, you can use your action on each of your turns to automatically deal 4d8 necrotic damage to the target. (...)

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. I edited the question mainly to cut a bit on the quote to include only the relevant part. Feel free to revert or [edit] further if you don't like some change. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes she still take the 2d8 damage.

The Enervation says "On a successful save, the target takes 2d8 ... On a failed save, the target takes 4d8 necrotic damage". Slayer's Counter will automatically set the saving throw to successful, which mean you need to make every single step in the success thread of the Enervation (2d8 damage).

The concentration is not like the magical words for creating a spell, but the opportunity to make the effect longer.